# Can the command prompt not execute commands on paste?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I'm using Windows 10. Most often I copy/paste some command into the command prompt that needs to be modified say for example

`composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.1.*"`

I copied pasted the command from Laravel docs and `blog` needs to be changed.

The thing is, as soon as I paste it, the command prompt starts executing it, I think it's detecting a space at the end of the line somewhere. Can that be fixed?

Comment: If you have included a new-line in the pasted text, the command will be executed immediately. Omit the new-line, and the text will stay on the input line until `Enter` is pressed, allowing it to be edited first.

Comment: @AFH I know but can the CMD omit the line automatically? Because if I have to do it manually,  it means that I copy something, paste it in a text editor, omit it, then copy it again and paste it. And I have to do that for everything, just in case

Comment: A workaround in cmd.exe is to type `rem`+space, paste the command, let it be ignored, hit up key, remove `rem` and edit freely.

Comment: Just be selective about what you copy from the source file. If you copy the carriage return, it'll paste into command prompt as a carriage return. if you edit your source file in Notepad++, you can enable to ability to view > show symbol > all characters which will show a |CR| |LF| at the end of each line

Comment: Just to add to what @spikey_richie have already said, if you use `Ctrl + A` to select the entire text, it also select a carriage return at the end. So you may have to avoid it.

Comment: If you select by dragging from the end of the string instead of the beginning, you are less likely to include an inadvertent trailing new-line.

Comment: @AFH: Why don't you put all this into an answer?

Comment: @harrymc - I've done as you suggest, while giving Kamil Maciorowski credit for his interesting alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you paste text with a trailing new-line into `cmd`, then the text will be executed as a command immediately.

The easiest way I have found to avoid this is to select by clicking at the end of the text, then dragging to the beginning. If you accidentally include an extra new-line it will be before the text, which will execute a blank line, before filling the next line with the text you want, but not executing it.

Alternatively, you could use Kamil Maciorowski's suggestion, to type `rem` (or `::`) at the start of the line before pasting, so that if the line does execute, it will be a comment, which can then be edited with history editing or cutting and pasting within `cmd` itself.

This effectively does what you ask, stopping a pasted command executing immediately, even if there is a trailing new-line, though I prefer to make sure that there is no new-line in the pasted text.